# Duplicate users

Tags: username

In attempting to change my username, I ended up with several copies of the user **temp**  .Here is the result of **who**:

```
temp     tty1         2020-08-20 15:02 (:0)
temp     pts/0        2020-08-20 15:02 (:0)
temp     pts/1        2020-08-20 15:02 (:0)
```

How can I get rid of them?

I was trying to change the username by creating a user **temp**, giving **temp** root privileges, then logging in as **temp** and then using **usermod**.  Somehow that got messed up.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? What you're showing is 3 login sessions, each trying to access X display `:0`. What did you do at `15:02` to create them? Exactly what does "attempting to change my username" mean? You can get a list of PIDs to kill with `ps -fu temp`. Read `man ps kill signal`

Comment: I'm running Kubuntu, not Ubuntu.  I don't know what  I did to get those pseudoterminals, but I don't seem to be able to deactivate them, nor can I delete the user "temp".

Comment: `sudo lsof /dev/tty1` will show processes on `/dev/tty1`.

Comment: Reboot gracefully, and they will all go away. tty1 is a text console (like CTRL+ALT+F2), pts/0 and pts/1 are likely different terminal windows in Kubuntu.